# Migrating data from TFS 2015 to TFS 2018

Tags: tfs

I am working in a Project where we are migrating data from TFS 2015 to TFS 2018.
In TFS 2015 we had some customizations (not native) and as sos we would like to start the process in TFS 2018, using Agile templates.
However we would like to migrate the data from TFS 2015 to TFS 2018.
Can anyone tell me what's the best way to achieve this?

Note1: TFS 2015 is in one Machine different from TFS 2018.

Comment: Did you start by reading Microsoft's documentation on TFS upgrades? It's easily googled.

Comment: Of course. But this is not a regular upgrade. This is a migration of data from a TFS 2015 placed in a machine to a TFS 2018 placed in another machine. If you could find proper Microsoft documentation about this please share it.

Comment: That's a regular upgrade scenario. Upgrade + new hardware.

Comment: Documentation url please.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you want to migrate datas on new hardware and database. Unlike  In-Place Upgrade, it should be a Migration based upgrade.

A simple process for your reference:

1. The first thing is checking the [Requirements and compatibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/he-il/tfs/server/requirements?view=vsts)
       for TFS 2018 and prepare the hardware according to the requirements.
2. Then you should create a backup to the current SQL database used in
       TFS 2015.
3. Upgrade the tfs according [this](https://www.benday.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/benday-tfs2018-install-guide-v1.1.pdf)  detailed guide.
4. Configure new features.

Recommend you firstly read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/tfs/server/upgrade/get-started) Microsoft article about TFS upgrades.

In addition, you can also take a look at this useful- "[Upgrade to TFS 2018 Has Been Done in Production](http://mohamedradwan.com/2018/01/16/upgrade-to-tfs-2018-has-been-done-in-production/)".